Pyrogram/Telethon Message not received from a certain telegram channel
I'm trying to write a program that automatically parses messages that are broadcasted in a particular channel. We'll use channel ID -100123456 for now. I have tried both Pyrogram and Telethon libraries and neither one seems to catch the events triggered by messages being broadcasted in this channel. The simple test program I wrote does in fact catch messages sent to my by individuals, or posted in groups, or even posted in other channels. Just not from channel -100123456. Below is sample program.
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client("EventHandling", api_id = XXXXXX, api_hash = 'XXXXXX')

@app.on_message()
async def echo(client, msg):
    print(msg)

app.run()

Not sure if this particular channel has a setting that prevents this from happening. Below is some of the info on the channel, just in case, as extracted using Pyrogram's get_chat(-100123456):
{
    "_": "Chat",
    "id": -100123456,
    "type": "ChatType.CHANNEL",
    "is_verified": false,
    "is_restricted": false,
    "is_creator": false,
    "is_scam": false,
    "is_fake": false,
    "title": "The Title",
    "description": "The Description",
    "dc_id": 1,
    "has_protected_content": true,
    "can_set_sticker_set": false,
    "members_count": 23169,
    "available_reactions": {
    ....

I am, however, able to fetch the messages from that channel by using Pyrogram's get_chat_history() as well as Telethon's get_messages() methods.
I have tried all the event handlers that Pyrogram and Telethon offer, including their respective:
MessageHandler
EditedMessageHandler
DeletedMessagesHandler
CallbackQueryHandler
InlineQueryHandler
ChosenInlineResultHandler
ChatMemberUpdatedHandler
UserStatusHandler
PollHandler
DisconnectHandler
RawUpdateHandler

and none were able to catch those events.
As an alternative work around, I have a while True loop that runs forever calling the respective get_chat_history() / get_messages() method from Pyrogram/Telethon, sleep for some time, and then repeat.

I was able to figure out a solution using Telethon:
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

with TelegramClient('EventHandling', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   @client.on(events.NewMessage(-100123456))
   async def handler(event):
       print(event)

   client.run_until_disconnected()

So, seems that when you specify the channel ID in the events.NewMessage, Telethon is able to catch those events whereas if you just leave it blank as in events.NewMessage(), it catches everything but those messages from that particular channel.
I was not able to get Pyrogram using a similar approach. I tried adding a filter to the event as shown below but it did not work as expected.
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("EventHandling", api_id, api_hash)

@app.on_message(filters.regex("-100123456"))
async def echo(client, msg):
    print(msg)

app.run()

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's just not supported by Pyrogram. I'll be using Telethon for my project.
